# Facebook Login/Register with my database

Tags: facebook, authentication, sign

I have a website with my custom register system (really simple - username, password and e-mail).
I want to make Login with facebook as my new and only register/login system.
I want to put a login button which:
 - if user is logged to facebook just asks for permission to use e-mail and other data + asks for custom username
 - if user is not logged, then just facebook login

Then the user would not need to login to my page if he's logged in to Facebook.

Can you please give me a hint or suggest a framwork to do this with?

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the Facebook developers page it tells you how to do this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login